# How to retrieve the Microsoft Edge Engine from One Drive ? Please help me?

Tags: windows-10

Please help me to retrieve the Microsoft Edge that I  made mistake by sending it to One Drive

Comment: Just make a new Edge shortcut.  Start, Apps, All Apps, Microsoft Edge, right click, More, open file location, and make the shortcut.

Comment: This may be a translation issue, but could you explain what you mean by the "Edge Engine"? Edge is the browser, but what is the "engine" you're referring to? What is missing or broken? Also, perhaps explaining what happened as you "sent it to OneDrive" may be helpful to our understanding your situation.